# Applying attribute specificity to an Angular CSS Directive Selector?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

In [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cpfxig?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) the `el_select` directive is used to change the style of the Angular Material Select component.  This is the demo html template:

```
<mat-form-field [el_select]="{ height: '52px', radius: '55px'}" appearance="outline" class="custom-field">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" panelClass="select-panel">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping"
      >{{topping}}</mat-option
    >
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I'm also trying to use the style sheet to apply styles that are not dynamic.  If I apply the styles using the class `custom-field` like this it works:

```
.custom-field
  .mat-mdc-form-field-flex
  .mdc-notched-outline
  .mdc-notched-outline__notch
  label {
  top: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

However if I change the selector so that it uses the `mat-form-field[el_select]` for specificity, instead of `custom-field`, the selector is no longer applied.

I expected that this CSS should be interchangeable with the `custom-field` CSS:

```
mat-form-field[el_select]
  .mat-mdc-form-field-flex
  .mdc-notched-outline
  .mdc-notched-outline__notch
  label {
  top: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Any ideas as to why it is not applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bracketed Angular inputs are not represented in the DOM.

You could match the property declaration by adding a host binding to your directive.

```
 @HostBinding('attr.my-attr')
```

Comment: OK ... so if it was just an attribute with no equal sign (no input) it would work ... but because it is an input ( ...equal sign ) it's not recognized by the CSS selector engine?

Comment: It’s more that directive are not represented into the DOM !

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add some additional context.

If we use Angular `@Input()` properties surround by brackets, we cannot select them using a `@Directive` selector.

For example this does not work:

```
<button [status]="colorInput">input</button>
```

However this does work:

```
<button status="success">hello</button>
```

[Here's a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cpfxig?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Here's the code for the directive.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

export type ColorClasses =
  | 'primary'
  | 'accent'
  | 'warn'
  | 'success'
  | undefined;

@Directive({
  selector: 'button[status]',
})
export class ElColorDirective {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    console.log('Color Directive Constructed');
  }

  @Input() set status(value: ColorClasses) {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.element.nativeElement, `mat-${value}`);
  }
}
```

We can also pass in JSON objects, however we have to parse the JSON to get the Javascript object.

[Here's a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aqidqm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcolor.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { Color } from './color.interface';

export type ColorClasses =
  | 'primary'
  | 'accent'
  | 'warn'
  | 'success'
  | undefined;

@Directive({
  selector: 'button[config]',
})
export class ElColorDirective {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    console.log('Color Directive Constructed');
  }

  @Input() set config(value: string) {
    console.log(value);
    const c: Color = JSON.parse(value);
    console.log(c.color);
  }
}
```